# How do I return to the first event after the second event gets executed?

Tags: python, events, discord

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user: 
    return

  if message.content == 'Hey Sloime':
    if message.author.id == xxx:
      await message.channel.send('Yes master?')
    elif message.author.id == xxx:
      await message.channel.send('Tell me brother')
    else:
      await message.channel.send('TF u want?')
  else:
    return

  @client.event
  async def on_message(message):

    if message.author == client.user:
      return
    if message.content == 'Can I have my Dis ID?':
      await message.channel.send(message.author.id)
    else:
      await message.channel.send('Do I look like I can answer that?')

  return


client.run(os.environ['TOKEN'])
```

It's my first time ever coding in Python, I have experience coding in c, c++, java and sql. My problem is that after I enter the second event on this bot I want to wait for a message corresponding to the first event, but it keeps looping on the second event, I apologize in advance if this is very simple.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```python
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == 'i want cheese':
        await message.channel.send('how much?')
        msg = await client.wait_for('message')
        await message.channel.send(f'ok, you want {msg.content} cheese')

    
         # you can do a check like this also
         msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=lambda msg: msg.author.id == xxx)
```

wait_for('message') waits for a message to happen